# In Android, how to pick a contact and display it on my app?

Tags: android, contacts

I am a beginner to android, i am building a application in which when the user presses a button, the contacts which is stored in the mobile are shown. When he selects a contact from that, i have to get the selected contact name and number. I tried using the code but only the name of the selected contact is shown and not the phone number.

```
public void readcontact(){
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people"));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
              Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                startManagingCursor(c);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));  
                  String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
                  perrsonname.setText(name);
                  Toast.makeText(this,  name + " has number " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
           }
         break;
      }

  }
```

I even need the additional number(home,office etc.,)of the selected contacts, 
 Can anyone help me out with this. Suggestions on this is appreciable.

Comment: Whats that can u explain me briefly?pls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer Contacts Application which comes with Android Source

Answer (score 3):

```
  public void readcontact(){ 
    try { 
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI); // creates the contact list intent
        contactPickerIntent.setType(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_TYPE); // selects contacts with phone only
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT); 

    } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 
 
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data); 
 
      switch (reqCode) { 
        case (PICK_CONTACT) : 
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
              Uri contactData = data.getData(); // has the uri for picked contact
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null); // creates the contact cursor with the returned uri
                if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
                   String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                   String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
                   Toast.makeText(this,  name + " has number " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                 } 
           } 
         break; 
      } 
 
  }
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation for the code you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Here i will demonstrate you that how to pick a contact no and name from a contact list on click or focus event,

**Focus Event:-**

```
     phoneNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
      {   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
          {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT );//PICK_CONTACT is private static final int, so declare in activity class
       } });
```

- A FUNCTION TO GET THE CONTACT NAME AND PHONE NO IS :

  ```
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
       super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

          switch(reqCode){
             case (PICK_CONTACT):
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
               {
                   Uri contactData = data.getData();
                   Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String id =   
                  c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                String hasPhone =
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
               Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                            null, null);
                  phones.moveToFirst();
                  String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                  String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 Toast.makeText(this, "contact info : "+ phn_no+"\n"+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                  }
               }
          }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, PICK_CONTACT_RQCODE_OLD);
            startActivity(intent1);
```

This works in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

#### This gives all the phone numbers from a picked contact in a hassle free manner

Start the Contact Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

Now use the following to get all the data,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(reqCode){
       case (PICK_CONTACT):
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
             Uri contactData = data.getData();
             Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
             ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

             if (c.moveToFirst())
             {
                 try
                 {
                     String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                     if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                     {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                        null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                        String phone = "";
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                phone = phone + pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1)) + ",";
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        } 
                        pCur.close();
                        if(phone.length() > 0)
                        {
                            phone = phone.substring(0,phone.length()-1);
                        }
                        txtPhone.setText(phone);
                     }
                     txtName.setText(name); 
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(AddToInnerCircle.this, "No name selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I've found to pick a contact with phone number, and show display name and the selected phone number. See also: [full, executable example as gist](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/f6324fceed582b84aa2a51c1a3fbad20).

```
private final static int PICK_CONTACT = 0;

private void pickContact() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

    // Show only contacts with phone number. (Also forces user to choose ONE 
    // phone number for a contact that has several.)
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                handleSelectedContact(data);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void handleSelectedContact(Intent intent) {
    Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String selectedPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.DATA1));

        String message = String.format("Name %s, selected phone %s", name, selectedPhone);
        Snackbar.make(contentView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    c.close();
}
```

If you need other fields, for example *both phone number and email*, check out [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14069375/56285).