# How to get the birthday of a picked contact

Tags: android, contacts

I am writing an app where the user has to pick a contact and is then referred back to the activity. [I used the code of the first answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830184/in-android-how-to-pick-a-contact-and-display-it-on-my-app?rq=1).

But beside the name of the contact, I also need the birthday. I have looked for questions to retrieve the birthday of the picked contact, but I only found answers on how to get a list of the birthdays of all Contacts, and not only for the picked contact. I have tried workarounds but no luck so far.

Any help?