# How to get contact id from uri?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I want to get specific contact id and name. what is the best way to get it?

```
if (requestCode == mActions.REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   Uri uriContact = (Uri)data.getData();
        String/int id = ???
        String name = ???
        String phoneNumber = ???
    }
  }
```

I just want to get the contact i choose data and not all the contact. how can i do it?

Comment: What does `uriContact.getPath()` contain?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067006/2278598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get Contact metadata if you've contact URI.

```
String id, name, phone, hasPhone;
int idx;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null,   null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
   id = cursor.getString(idx);

   idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
   name = cursor.getString(idx);

   idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
   hasPhone = cursor.getString(idx);
```

}