# Obtaining Email Addresses of Specific Contact Without Permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, registerforactivityresult

I can easily get a list of every email address for every Contact using the following example snippets:

```
//...
private val getPerson = registerForActivityResult(PickContact()) {
        it?.also { contactUri ->
            val personDetails = ContactForPerson("", "", "")

            val projection = arrayOf(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,          //String
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,//String
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,             //String
            )

            context?.contentResolver?.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null)?.apply {
                moveToFirst()
                personDetails.apply {
                    uri = getStringOrNull(0)
                    name = getString(1)
                    email = getStringOrNull(2)
                }
                close()
            }
        }
    }

//...

fab.setOnClickListener {
//...
          getPerson.launch(0)
//...
}

//...

class PickContact : ActivityResultContract<Int, Uri?>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Int?) =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI).also {
                it.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE
            }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? =
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) intent?.data else null
}
```

The question is, since I already have some information about a Contact, is there a way for me to filter the giant list of every email address for every Contact to only show me the email addresses for a single Contact?

I noticed [Get specific contact information from URI returned from Intent.ACTION_PICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069375/get-specific-contact-information-from-uri-returned-from-intent-action-pick), but the information is rather dated and it's not clear if the READ_CONTACTS permission is required, which is not desired.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're calling an EMAIL-PICKER and not a CONTACT-PICKER, by setting the intent type to `Email.CONTENT_TYPE`.

This means the user will be choosing a specific email in the device's default contacts app.

The result you're then getting from the picker is **not** a `contactUri`, rather a `dataUri` - i.e. a uri that points to a specific row in the `Data` table, which only allows you to get info about that specific row, in this case it must be an email row.

This also means your projection is a bit funny by using fields under `CommonDataKinds.Phone.X`, this doesn't matter too much as these fields are inherited from Data.CONTENT_URI, but to prevent confusion you should probably replace these with:

```
Data.LOOKUP_KEY, 
Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
Email.ADDRESS,
```

Now, if you want all the contact's email rather then a single one, you should not set the intent type - this will launch a contact picker which will allow you to get the contact's emails + phones + name by retrieving the Entity as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082019/819355).