# Contact URI vs. _ID/LOOKUP_KEY

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I'm working on Android 4.2.2.

Say I have a contact called "Home".  I use a basic contact picker such as:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
```

...and then in the onActivityResult I get the contact URI:

```
String contactUri = data.getDataString();
```

Let's say it comes back with `content://com.android.contacts/data/10855`.

But now in another part of the application, I'm watching for incoming calls.  When the call comes in I'm trying to find the calling contact URI:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
             Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone_nbr)),
             new String[] {PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,PhoneLookup._ID},
             null, null, null);
```

I was guessing that the 10855 would be in either LOOKUP_KEY or _ID.  It happens to be neither, so I guess I'm going about it the wrong way.  Can someone advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533896) I'd say to use the URI returned and find the lookup key from there.

Something like this might work:

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
String key = null;
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) { 
  key = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY));
}
```

Comment: hmm, I've got a problem, since code like above doesn't seem to allow getting contacts. App has permissions to read contacts